# Image not saving into directory after cropping

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to save cropped image after cropping into a directory but when i click on crop button nothing happens. I am stuck in it from 2 days please someone help me out.
I am getting these errors

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(public/image/) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\ModuleEx.com\application\modules\admin\controllers\IndexController.php on line 64

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(public/image/) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\ModuleEx.com\application\modules\admin\controllers\IndexController.php on line 64

Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open 'public/image/crop' for writing: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\ModuleEx.com\application\modules\admin\controllers\IndexController.php on line 71

Here is my controller code

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){ //user upload file
    $file_name = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $ext_idx = strrpos($file_name,".");
    if(!$ext_idx) //hide this if ur app can upload without ext
        echo "File invalid.";
    else{
        $ext_length = strlen($file_name) - $ext_idx;
        $extension = strtolower(substr($file_name,$ext_idx+1,$ext_length));
        //allowed extension
        $ext_list = array("pdf", "doc","jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
        if(!in_array($extension, $ext_list))
            echo "System can't support your extension.";
        else{
            $size = (2500 * 1024); //2500 Kb
            $file_size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            if($file_size > $size)
                echo "File is oversize. Max 2500 Kb.";
            else{
                //change name
                $file_name = rand(10,1000).".".$extension;

                $file_obj="public/image/".$file_name;



                $copied = copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file_obj);

                if(!$copied)
                    echo "Failed.";
                else 
                {

                    $file_data = array( 'file_name' => $file_name );


                    $this->view->file_obj=$file_obj;




                }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my phtml code.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 {
$targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
$jpeg_quality = 90;

 $src = 'file_obj';
$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
 $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

 imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,(int)$_POST['x'],(int)$_POST['y'],
 $targ_w,$targ_h,(int)$_POST['w'],(int)$_POST['h']);

 //header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  imagejpeg($dst_r,'file_obj',$jpeg_quality);

   }


    ?>




 <html>
  <head>

   <script src="public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="public/js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
   <script src="public/js/jquery.color.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">


  $(function(){

  $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
aspectRatio: 1,
onSelect: updateCoords
 });

   });

   function updateCoords(c)
   {
  $('#x').val(c.x);
 $('#y').val(c.y);
 $('#w').val(c.w);
 $('#h').val(c.h);
 };

 function checkCoords()
  {
 if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
 alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
 return false;
 };

  </script>


  <style type="text/css">
  #target {
   background-color: #ccc;
   width: 500px;
     height: 330px;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: block;
  }


  </style>


 <?=$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/public/css/demos.css');?>
 <?=$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/public/css/main.css');?>
 <?=$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/public/css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css');?>
</head>

<body>
   <form id="file_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" onsubmit="">
    <input type="file" name="file" />

     <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Upload"/><br/></br>
     <img id="cropbox" src="<?php echo $this->file_obj?>" alt="Image" style="display: block; visibility: visible; width: 602px; height: 400px; border: medium none; opacity: 0.5;"/><br/>

        <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
        <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
        <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
        <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
        <input type="submit" value="Crop Image" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" />
  </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
    $names = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
    $tmp = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
    $upload_dir = './images';
    $move=move_uploaded_file($tmp, "$upload_dir/$names");
    $a="./images/".$names;
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($a);
    $newwidth = "120"; 
    $newheight = "100";
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    if($_FILES["img"]["type"]=="image/jpeg"){
      $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($a);
    imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($thumb, $a, 100);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this code @ssk but i am still getting no such file or directory error @ this line  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($a);

Comment: then the problem is with your image path only... is your file moved successfully to the public folder? check for the $move..
if($move){echo "file moved";}else{echo "file not moved";}

Comment: Yes after upload file is successfully moving to /public/image folder but after selecting crop area when i click on crop button then cropped image is not saving into that directory.

Comment: on which platform you are using this? check for the file permissions.. If write permission is not allowed to that image file then it won't get cropped..

Comment: Thanks for the link but chmod doesn't work in windows :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps. 
* Where specifically does your folder(public/image) or it's path stored? Does it also lies with the same directory with your IndexController.php?

This is my code in saving an image in a folder:
    $path = "uploads/";

```
$actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
$tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE lms_users SET userPic='$actual_image_name' WHERE userId='$_SESSION[email]'");                       
    echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."'  class='preview'>";
}
else
echo "failed";
```

Hopes this helps.

Comment: This is image directory path C:\wamp\www\ModuleEx.com\public\image

Comment: and this is controller path C:\wamp\www\ModuleEx.com\application\modules\admin\controllers

Comment: try making a public/image folder along with your IndexController.php directory. Your system/program will search the public/image along with your indexController.php in this code:                                     

      $file_obj="public/image/".$file_name;

Comment: Does this codes or sources:

<script src="public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="public/js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
<script src="public/js/jquery.color.js"></script>

Is it also stored along with your indexController.php? If its not then try to transfer it as well.